# Re-using sqlite3 statement for new query

Tags: c++, sqlite

In order to commit an sqlite query in C++ we need to create an `sqlite3_stmt`, prepare it via `sqlite3_prepare_v2`, `sqlite3_bind_` potential values to the statement and then `sqlite3_step` through it.

Now, in a function that e.g. performs two separate sqlite queries, can I just re-use the same `sqlite3_stmt` by calling `sqlite3_prepare_v2` on it again or do I need to explicitly `sqlite3_reset` the statement beforehand?

E.g.

```
void mySqliteFunction() {
    sqlite3_stmt* stmt;
    int rc;
    rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(<connection>, <sql string>, ..., &stmt, ...);
    rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
    if (rc == SQLITE_OK) {
        rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(<connection>, <other sql string>, ..., &stmt, ...); // is this valid?
        rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
    }
    rc = sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Why prepare one statement then immediately discard it?

Comment: @jarmod Thank you, I forgot the `step` in the pseudo code and updated my question accordingly. Do you now understand what I mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `stmt` prepared statement variable in your code simply holds a handle for the prepared statement and its value is populated by the `sqlite3_prepare_v2()` call.

The problem in your code currently is that you fail to finalize correctly. You are responsible for deleting the compiled SQL statement using `sqlite3_finalize()`. If you correctly finalized the initial prepared statement after use, then you could reuse the `stmt` variable, otherwise you are leaking resources.

The `sqlite3_reset()` function is designed to reset a given prepared statement to allow it to be re-executed. It's not designed for the case where you will actually prepare a different SQL statement.

Comment: It's important to note that I don't want to use it to execute the exact same statement with other bindings. The first `<sql string>` might insert a row, the second `<other sql string>` may be a select query...